# wrong rename with python

Tags: python, ubuntu, rename, exif

I need to rename my picture with the EXIF data, but I have a problem: if I use ":" to separate the time (hour:minute:second), the file name gets crazy!

```
metadata = pyexiv2.ImageMetadata(lunga + i)
metadata.read()
tag = metadata['Exif.Image.DateTime']
estensione = ".jpg"
new_data = tag.value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')
new_name = lunga + str(new_data) + estensione
os.renames(lunga + i, new_name)
```

works great, but with

```
    new_data = tag.value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I get something like

```
2A443K~H.jpg
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're on Windows, right?

Comment: colons are not allowed in file names on many systems, so maybe try underscore instead?

Comment: @beroe: Actually, most systems allow them; it's basically just Windows (and classic Mac, but nobody uses that anymore); OS X, linux, etc. do.

Comment: Yep, I guess I was thinking back to my "classic Mac" days.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not allowed to put colons into filenames on Windows. You're not actually using Windows… but you *are* using an SMB share, which means you're bound by Windows rules.

The fix is to not put colons into your filenames.

If you want to understand why this bizarre stuff is happening, read on.

---

The details on Windows filenames are described in [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at MSDN, but I'll summarize the relevant parts here.

The NT kernel underneath Windows has no problems with colons, but the Win32 layer on top of it can't handle them (and the quasi-POSIX layer in MSVCRT sits on top of Win32).

So, at the C level, if you call NT functions like [`NtSetInformationFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557671%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it will save them just fine. If you call Win32 functions like [`MoveFileEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), they will normally give you an error, but if you use the special `\\?\` syntax to say "pass this name straight through to NT", it will work. And if you call MSVCRT functions like `rename`, you will get an error. Older versions of Python called `rename`, which would just give you an error. Newer versions call `MoveFileEx`, and will try to wrap the name up in `\\?\` syntax (because that also allows you to get around some other stupid limitations, like the excessively short `MAX_PATH` value).

So, what happens if you give a file a name that Win32 can't understand? Remember that on Windows, every file has two different names: the "long name" and the "short name". The short name is a DOS-style 8.3 filename. So whenever it can't display the long name, it displays the short name instead.

Where does the short name come from? If you don't create one explicitly, Windows will create one for you from the long name by using the first 6 characters, a tilde, and a number of letter. So, for example, the short name for `"Program Files"` is `"PROGRA~1"`. But if Windows can't handle the long name, it will just make up a short name out of 6 random characters, a tilde, and a random character. So you get something like `2A443K~H`.

The NTFS filesystem, being designed for Windows, expects to be used in Windows-y ways. So, if you're using an NTFS volume, even on a non-Windows system, the driver will emulate some of this functionality, giving you similar but not identical behavior.

And of course if you're talking to a share from a Windows system, or a share backed by an NTFS drive on a non-Windows system, again, some of the same things will apply.

Even if both your computer and the file server are non-Windows and the filesystem is not NTFS, if you're using SMB/CIFS for file sharing, SMB was also designed for Windows, and you will again get similar behavior.

At least you no longer have to worry about VMS, classic Mac, and other naming systems, just POSIX and Windows.

Comment: I'm not using windows, I am on UBUNTU

Comment: @user1835905: Is the file on an NTFS drive or an SMB share? If so, what you're seeing is probably the driver emulating crazy Windows behavior.

Comment: strike! i checked: on my ext4 partition works well, I get the error on SMB share...

Comment: @user1835905: OK, I'll edit the answer to explain why SMB shares force every OS to work like Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Colons are reserved characters in Windows filesystem (see [How would I go about creating a filename with invalid characters such as :?>?](https://superuser.com/questions/187469/how-would-i-go-about-creating-a-filename-with-invalid-characters-such-as)), so the name was replaced with an auto-generated on instead.

To be clear, this is *not* a Python issue. Don't use colons or other reserved characters in filenames if you don't want this to happen.

Comment: I'm not using windows, I am on UBUNTU

Comment: @user1835905: same problem there, depending on the file system.